# Closedness of second order PDE with complex coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Is the following operator closed on $L^2(-1,1)$?
\begin{equation}
Tu=(c u')',\quad \mathcal{D}(T)=\{u\in H^2(-1,1):u(-1)=u(1)=0\}
\end{equation}
Here $c$ is a smooth complex-valued coefficient that is non-vanishing (bounded away from zero) on the interval. I'm aware the operator is closable but want to figure out if it closed and if not, what the domain of its closure is. Most texts I can find treat the case of real coefficients (where of course one can say a lot more). Really what I am after is a method of showing these kind of operators are closed (if they are!) or a nice counterexample. Something that can be extended to higher order (e.g. fourth) derivatives in divergence form as well.